# как сделать так чтобы бот не мог удалить свое сообщения?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

у меня такая проблема, что мой бот удаляет например сообщения содержащее слово "пидр", но у меня команда, которую если написать, то бот напишет пидр, вот как сделать так, чтобы он не мог сам себя так сказать удалить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте проверку, является ли автор сообщения конкретным ботом:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # если автор сообщения - этот бот
    if message.author == bot.user:
        # завершаем выполнение функции выполняя возврат
        return
    
    # здесь ваш остальной код
    ...
```

Comment: спасибо большое!! а можно чтобы он не мог удалять сообщения выше своей роли?

Comment: Сходу не скажу как это сделать. Можно в документации найти как называется свойство, обозначающее позицию в писке ролей, у объекта роли и сравнивать эти свойства у роли бота и у роли автора сообщения.

Comment: прочитал, нашел только о guild, role, я был сонный

Comment: @mafinpy если я не ошибаюсь, у роли свойство называется `position`

Comment: всо равно не понимаю, if message.author.role_position >= bot.user.role.position:

Comment: @mafinpy вероятно, вам нужна самая главная роль пользователя, это свойство `top_role` и уже у нее нужно брать позицию, то есть `message.author.top_role.position`. Как вы нашли в документации свойство `role_position` я не знаю)

Comment: аа, понял, я писал message.author.top_role и все, чего то не хватало, всо спасибо большое